# "weather today fine but high waves" - what is the Japanese for this?

Tags: phrases, culture

This is a famous phrase from the Battle of Tsushima in the Russo-Japanese war. It is used in modern times such as by Shinzo Abe after he called a snap election a couple of years ago.

You can research it and get more examples I am sure.

Anyway, I am having difficulty in finding the original Japanese. I can guess it would be something like

```
今日の天気はいいですけど、なみが高いです
```

but I bet it is more poetic than my child's Japanese :)

Does anybody know it?

Comment: 「本日天気晴朗ナレドモ浪高シ」だそうです。http://englishmaxims.seesaa.net/article/430181878.html　Wikiにも: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%B5%B7%E6%B5%B7%E6%88%A6#.E9.80.A3.E5.90.88.E8.89.A6.E9.9A.8A.E5.87.BA.E6.92.83

Comment: I'm converting the comment into a community wiki answer since the question doesn't seem to be going to get closed as off-topic, nor does it seem like anyone's going to post an answer (probably because of my comment being there...)

Answer (score 2):

According to these pages ([1](http://englishmaxims.seesaa.net/article/430181878.html), [2](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%B5%B7%E6%B5%B7%E6%88%A6#.E9.80.A3.E5.90.88.E8.89.A6.E9.9A.8A.E5.87.BA.E6.92.83)), it seems like the original Japanese is:

> 本日天気晴朗ナレドモ浪高シ